# How to open multiple files with cursor for all files being at the last line?

Tags: multiple-files, line-numbers, open

My experiments generate several log files, which I sometimes monitor manually. Some of the log files have an error message in the last line.

I want to open all log files with the cursor located at the last line. One solution can be

```
vim file1.log:128 file2.log:277
```

with last line numbers `128` and `277` determined by some wrapper code.

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Would it work to generate a quickfix list and use `-q`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
vim *.log +'argdo norm! G'
```

See

- [`:h [+cmd]`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%5b%2bcmd%5d)
- [`:h :argdo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Aargdo)
- [`:h :norm`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Anorm)

The `+ [cmd]` allows you to run an ex command when you start vim and the command `argdo norm! G` will run `norm! G` on all the files being opened.

Of course you can replace `*.log` by the list of files you want to open.

*EDIT* to address the comments:

[`:h :$`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3A%24) being a valid ex commands `norm! G` can be replaced by `$` to save some keystrokes

```
vim *.log +'argdo $'
```

And if you invoke Vim with the `-p` parameter which opens every buffers in their own tab you can replace `argdo` by `tabdo` to have the command executed on every tab instead of every buffers.

Comment: Can change `norm! G` for a single `$`

Comment: @Matt It depends on what you want to do, as `:h norm` says this commands allows you to write as an ex command a normal mode command. Which means that `norm G` is the equivalent of pressing `G` while you are in normal mode i.e. going to the last line of the file. If you use `norm $` you will put your cursor at the end of the first line.

Comment: I mean only `$` without `norm`. That's an Ex command itself.

Comment: Yeah... As @Matt said, `vim *.log +'argdo $'` is more straightforward.

Comment: @filbranden In this particular case yes. But in general, I would prefer `:norm! G`, because of a few pitfalls with `$`.

Comment: @user938271 Can you elaborate on the pitfalls with `$`?

Comment: @filbranden If the command contains a single quote, you may be tempted to surround it with double quotes instead of single quotes. In a double-quoted string, bash and zsh may interpret the dollar sign as a reference to an environment variable name (this can happen for example if you try to run a global command whose last line specifier is `$`).

Comment: @filbranden If you run a command consisting of only a line specifier, and if it's followed by another command separated by a bar, Vim seems to interpret the line specifier command as `:p`, so in addition to moving the cursor on the line, it also has the undesired effect of printing it (compare `:$` vs `:$|let var=0`; both move the cursor, but the second one also prints the last line). To avoid this pitfall, you can use `:exe` (e.g. `:exe '$'|let var=0`).

Comment: @Matt oh right I forgot about this command because I never use it, but it should work

Comment: Solution is working. But I use tab view for viewing multiple files. When I do `vim -p *.log +'argdo norm! G'`, ONLY in the first file is the cursor at last last. Can you generalize your answer to tab view?

Comment: @user3342981 Replace `:argdo` with `:tabdo` (`vim -p *.log +'tabdo norm! G'`). If later you have several windows per tab page, then use `:tabdo windo` (`vim -p *.log +'tabdo windo norm! G'`).